# When the window menu is in the title bar, how can I set the focus click to not open a menu?

Tags: unity, menu, focus

Ubuntu 15.04 x64

I use the setting: "Show the menu for a window: In the window's title bar" [Settings > Appearance > Behavior]. When a window is in the background, I only want to bring it to the foreground when I click the window title bar, not open a menu. How can I set this behavior?

I have looked in Unity Tweak and CompizConfig but have not found a relevant setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not in the middle of the settings, it can be accessed with dconf editor . Or simply run

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.IntegratedMenus unfocused-windows-popup false
```